# How to release resources on force close of activity

Tags: android

i am using camera resource in my activity
some time activity does not respond and ask for force close
how can we release our resources on force close of activity

Comment: you'd better find out why it force closes (*asks* for? is it an Application Not Responding issue?)

Comment: ya! i am capturing image using camera in my activity but it is not responding for long and finally ask for force close. after that i could not open any app related to cam

Comment: you should post a question to solve the ANR. if the app just gets killed by the system, i don't know how many chances you have to release resources. see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855745/handle-force-close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Once Android needs to force close your app, it's already past the point where you can execute any code.

However, Android should release your resources for you so you shouldn't need to worry.

Comment: my camera resource is not getting released

Comment: @bigstones is correct - you need to fix the reason for force close or ANR. It almost sounds like you are blocking the UI thread, which will guarantee an ANR. If it is force closing, then you cannot release your resources. If you are getting ANR, you should be able to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is a method called `onLowMemory()` that can be overridden in any class where you can access context parameter. But it is called only when your application is running out of memory and you can perform only those tasks which do not require extra memory.

Comment: That's absolutely right, though at the point of a force close, it's already far beyond `onLowMemory()`, and `onLowMemory()` is only called if the force close was due to low memory. @Sunil really needs to address the reasons for the force close/ANR first.