# What happens when android app is force closed

Tags: android

I am interested to know what happens when a user click a "force close" in a pop up when application is not responding for a significant amount of time.

What all events will be fired?
Will the task removed from tray?

I think when an activity is force closed, dalvik will clean the app cache and start last activity in the back stack. But not sure how exactly it works.

Any input is appreciated.

Here is a resource I am looking at
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Force quit will kill the application, sending the SIGKILL signal to the process and thus killing the virtual machine. No signals are sent from the Virtual Machine to your application when this happens, and state won't be recovered after that.

Hope it helps.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855745/handle-force-close) that provides some details.

Also refer to [Designing for Responsiveness](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html) for tips on avoiding the ANR dialog.