# SIGABRT in __ioctl() while waiting for /dev/binder response

Tags: android, linux, sigabrt, ioctl, android-binder

Pre-requisites: ARMv7 device, Android platform 4.2.2.

Time to time I get SIGABRT upon interaction with a system service (a really buggy one) over a binder. The stack trace is as follows:

```
#00 pc 000170ac /system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+8)
#01 pc 0002aa8d /system/lib/libc.so (ioctl+16)
#02 pc 00016ba1 /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+132)
#03 pc 0001709d /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::waitForResponse(android::Parcel*, int*)+44)
#04 pc 000172b7 /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::transact(int, unsigned int, android::Parcel const&, android::Parcel*, unsigned int)+114)
#05 pc 00014a3b /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::BpBinder::transact(unsigned int, android::Parcel const&, android::Parcel*, unsigned int)+34)
```

__ioctl resolves to the following assembly code:

```
000170a4 <__ioctl>:
    170a4:  e92d0090 push   {r4, r7}
    170a8:  e3a07036 mov    r7, #54 ; 0x36
    170ac:  ef000000 svc    0x00000000
    170b0:  e8bd0090 pop    {r4, r7}
    170b4:  e1b00000 movs   r0, r0
    170b8:  512fff1e bxpl   lr
    170bc:  ea0093a6 b  3bf5c
```

The stack dump is triggered by signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_KILL), with a fault address like 0x304, 0x330, 0x33A (it differs time to time and I am not even sure whether it is really an address in any address space rather than an error code or a flag combination).

I have no idea what the signal might indicate, i.e. whether it is

- a driver error (but why is it relayed in such a strange way rather than over the return value?)
- an unintercepted driver fault (is that even possible without a kernel panic?);
- a kernel fault (outside the driver call and possibly unrelated to the driver);
- a broken interrupt vector (then why not SIGSEGV or SIGILL?);
- a result of SIGQUIT (Dalvik stack trace signal) received in supervisor mode.

In the last case, I take my amazement back and proceed to investigation of the blocking call freeze cause (deadlock in the called process?). Possibly, I can build a test application to reproduce this specific precondition but it will take time.

I found a number of similar-looking traces and bug reports [around the web](http://www.bing.com/search?q=sigabrt%20__ioctl%20libbinder), indicating that the issue is not device or vendor specific (though possibly platform version specific).

The exact service being interacted with does not matter either.

P.S. logcat:

```
03-21 16:21:22.933   772   831 I InputDispatcher: Application is not responding: Window{41000dd8 u0 my.application.package/my.application.package.MyActivity}.  It has been 5008.3ms since event, 5005.7ms since wait started.  Reason: Waiting because the touched window has not finished processing the input events that were previously delivered to it.
03-21 16:21:22.943   772   831 I WindowManager: Input event dispatching timed out sending to my.application.package/my.application.package.MyActivity
03-21 16:21:23.163   772   831 I Process : Sending signal. PID: 16195 SIG: 3
03-21 16:21:23.163 16195 16200 I dalvikvm: threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
03-21 16:21:23.263 16195 16200 I dalvikvm: Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
03-21 16:21:23.273   772   831 E ActivityManager: ANR in my.application.package (my.application.package/my.application.package.MyActivity)
03-21 16:21:23.273   772   831 E ActivityManager: Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut
03-21 16:21:23.273   772   831 E ActivityManager: Load: 0.0 / 0.0 / 0.0
03-21 16:21:23.273   772   831 E ActivityManager: CPU usage from 18140ms to 0ms ago:
-- CPU usage dump, nothing unusual --
03-21 16:21:23.273   772   831 E ActivityManager: 61% TOTAL: 33% user + 27% kernel + 0% iowait + 0.8% softirq
03-21 16:21:23.273   772   831 E ActivityManager: CPU usage from 5686369ms to 5686369ms ago with 0% awake:
03-21 16:21:23.273   772   831 E ActivityManager: 0% TOTAL: 0% user + 0% kernel
03-21 16:21:23.283   772   831 I Process : Sending signal. PID: 16195 SIG: 6
03-21 16:21:23.283 16195 16195 F libc    : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x00000304 (code=0), thread 16195 (my.application.package)
-- and then the stack dump --
```

Comment: Are you saying this occurs as a result of a blocking call blocking for too long?   If binder is blocking, it is probably because whatever userspace process you are interchanging with through binder is blocking.  I doubt the problem is with wrapper around the ioctl syscall specifically.  Perhaps this is just the mechanism behind an ANR timeout?  Can you provide a more complete logcat record (to see if something announces that it is sending a SIGABRT and *why*) or is the problem not one which happens while running your test device with ADB connected, but only shows up occasionally in the field?

Comment: Added a skimmed logcat dump. You might be right, as the signal originator - or at least the process that notifies the logger - is the same for SIGQUIT(3) and SIGABRT(6). But it's the first time I see SIGABRT in this role. Usually, it's SIGKILL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249271/what-happens-when-android-app-is-force-closed