# Get an Event when User FORCE CLOSE my application from settings in Android?

Tags: android, settings, forceclose

I am working to deal with the System services about my android application. I have to Authenticate user at the time when he/she Force Close the application. For this I am in a need to get an EVENT when user FORCE CLOSE the application from Settings. Please suggest me how can I achieve this ??

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855745/handle-force-close

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that by "Force Close" you mean "Force Stop" in Settings, this is not possible.