# Activity's onDestroy() method not called after removing activity from background by swiping

Tags: android

I have implemented `ActivityLifecycleCallbacks` in a private class inside my `Application` class.

If Home button or Back button is used, lifecycle's `onStop()` and `onPause()` methods are getting called. If I kill the activity by swiping out from background, `onDestroy()` method is not getting called. It gets called when I start my activity next time. I am using `moveTaskToBack(true)` in case of Back press.

What must be the issue and which lifecycle method should get called when we swipe out from background?

Comment: Swiping the app from the task list basically means "kill this app **right now**" it's not given any time to perform an onDestroy. None of the lifecycle methods will be called

Comment: @TimCastelijns Could you please provide a source? I believe it's changing across versions or devices. Because, I'm currently seeing that my execution flow enters onDestroy of my activity right after swiping the app task.

Answer (score 7):

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy()) of `onDestroy()`:

> Note: do not count on this method being called as a place for saving
>   data! For example, if an activity is editing data in a content
>   provider, those edits should be committed in either onPause() or
>   onSaveInstanceState(Bundle), not here. This method is usually
>   implemented to free resources like threads that are associated with an
>   activity, so that a destroyed activity does not leave such things
>   around while the rest of its application is still running. **There are
>   situations where the system will simply kill the activity's hosting
>   process without calling this method** (or any others) in it, so it
>   should not be used to do things that are intended to remain around
>   after the process goes away.

Such a situation is swiping the app out of the recent tasks list.

Check out **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38281674/3363481)** on how to get notified when the app is getting swiped out of Recents.

Answer (score 3):

I remember reading a similar question on StackOverflow. Here was the top answer:

**Handle exit application from Task Manager**
[Handle exit application from Task Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972339/handle-exit-application-from-task-manager)

> Unfortunately there isn't a good answer for handling this situation. If the app is force-killed, onDestroy method isn't necessarily called. According to the documentation.
>
> Note: do not count on this method being called as a place for saving data! For example, if an activity is editing data in a content provider, those edits should be committed in either onPause() or onSaveInstanceState(Bundle), not here.
>
> If you can, clean up in the onPause() method. In order for the user to get to that screen to kill the app, it has to have been backgrounded and thus onPause() would be called. (see documentation)

Answer (score 1):

swiping app from back ground i.e. clearing from recents causes the whole process and task to be killed and that time `onDestroy()` may not be called , when user presses back from an activity then only that activity is killed not the process.

Comment: *will not be called