# Android : When app close do something

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want when user close my app it update SQLite data then close app. I used `onPause()`, `onStop()` and `onDestroy()` method in different time on **MainActivity**. All methods work when app close.

**But The problem is**, *`onStop()`, `onPause()` and `onDestroy()` are called when I change activity. But I don't want to do it when I change activity, only when I close my app.*

How I can do that?

Thank you for your response.

Comment: You can override the method onBackPressed() in your main activity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The app will be closed

*1.When user pressed back button in Main activity*

*2.When you call finish() method programmatically*

Hence, You can use **onBackPressed()** method ,

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        //do your action
        finish();
        
    }
```

If you are finishing main activity programmatically, Then **do your task before calling finish()**

**Edit**

As you mentioned,

*3.when the app is closed from recent activities,*

Activity will be closed instantly. Activity Life cycle is not considered. Even onDestroy() method will not be invoked. Hence You can **use service to detect** that.

There is a method called `onTaskRemoved()` which can be used in your service

```
 @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        //do your task;
    }
```

You can get more info from **[this source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38281674/8867002)**

Comment: It's a good answer. But also have a limitation. If I click **close all** (pause app) button of my mobile then this method don't run. It run when I press back button to close app.
How I can run it when user close **pause app**?

Comment: when you are closing app from recent activities, it will be killed instantly. None of the life cycle method will be executed

Comment: @sharifulislam try edited solution and refer that link

Comment: `onDestroy()` method work when I close app form recent activities. But `onDestroy()` also run when I change activity.
This is the main problem. :(

Comment: `when I close app form recent activities` Then use service to do that

Comment: It's perfect. Lot of thanks :) <3
I used your both methods on activity and service.
Thank you lot.

Comment: onDestroy() will not run when you change the activity, untill and unless you call finish() method after passing intent in startActivity(intent); @sharifulislam

Comment: @HiteshSarsava when you are closing app, ondestroy() will be invoked. The question is not when app closed.

Comment: ondestroy() will be called only if you remove app from stack of Apps @JyotiJK

Comment: Please check activity lifecycle @HiteshSarsava

Comment: i mean what will happen if user press home button the middle one? @JyotiJK

Comment: @HiteshSarsava The app will be in background. It will be closed if you closed it from recent apps(stack of apps). Otherwise it will be in pause mode

Comment: i mean which method will be called when user press home button from mobile, the middle one ? @JyotiJK

Comment: I don't think I've ever closed an app by pressing "back". I usually just click "home" and then actually quit the app if I feel like I have too many apps open (by closing all open apps). So this answer is just misleading.